# How to restore notification icon for Automatic Suspend?

Tags: notifications

I've noticed that the icon on the Automatic Suspend notification had changed after installing the Zettlr application. I've noticed this happen with other apps as well.

[image]

Is there a way to restore the original icon?

Thanks,

Comment: Noting that the icon change happened after a reboot.

Comment: I've resolved the issue by deleting Zettlr, but I do not know the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have same issue but my icon somehow changed to Plex client icon.